# Why does commenting out the alert() line of this code make it fail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures, hoisting

I have a very odd problem with javascript. If you take the following code and run it, it will run fine without any error, but if you comment the first `alert`, it will throw an error at line 5 (`var _board = Bomber.BoardFactory.getBoard();`) saying BoardFactory doesn't exist (remember that with the first alert everything was running without error).  I have been able to reproduce this exact behavior with Firefox and Chrome.

```
Bomber = {};

Bomber.Game = function () {
    var self = {};
    var _board = Bomber.BoardFactory.getBoard();

    self.init = function () {};
    self.start = function () {};

    return self;
}

alert("2");

(function () {
    var instance;

    Bomber.BoardFactory = {};
    Bomber.BoardFactory.getBoard = function () {
        if (!instance)
            instance = new Bomber.Board();
        return instance;
    };
})();

alert("3");

Bomber.Board = function () {
    var self = {};
    return self;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var game = Bomber.Game();
    game.init();
    game.start();
});
```

My question, is what can possibly cause this odd behavior ? How on earth is it possible that an alert call makes it recognize the `Bomber.BoardFactory` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran it through jslint, fixed the errors (2 missing semicolons and missing {} on your if)

Now it seems to work

```
Bomber = {};

Bomber.Game = function () {
    var self = {};
    var _board = Bomber.BoardFactory.getBoard();

    self.init = function () {};
    self.start = function () {};

    return self;
};

//alert("2");

(function () {
    var instance;

    Bomber.BoardFactory = {};
    Bomber.BoardFactory.getBoard = function () {
        if (!instance){
            instance = new Bomber.Board();
        }
        return instance;
    };
})();

//alert("3");

Bomber.Board = function () {
    var self = {};
    return self;
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    var game = Bomber.Game();
    game.init();
    game.start();
});
```

What's happening is you're missing the final semicolon after you define `Bomber.Game`, so the next thing is (function()....etc, so it thinks you're calling the function.

If you have the alert there you are saved by automatic semicolon insertion.

Comment: @HoLyVieR only the first time it's seen :-) I don't use semi-colons except where required -- however, for expressions that start with a `(`, (or very rarely `[` but also `+` or `-`) I always precede them with a `;` such as: `;(function () {...})()`. JavaScript does utilize ASI but it *won't put in a semi-colon if the previous expression can be continued*. Since `...}\nalert(...` wasn't a valid expression JavaScript read it as `...};alert(...`. Happy coding.

Comment: @pst the semicolon is being inserted between the closing } of the function, and the line beginning `alert` (from what I understand of it)

Comment: @david Yeah, I read that wrong -- removed comment :) Good answer.

Comment: @pst it's always safer to put the semicolon in, rather than trying to game the system. If you're worried about size, run it through an optimiser/compiler, it will remove the semicolons you don't need.

Comment: @pst really? why take the risk of a random bug? I put it *everywhere* its needed, just in case. I don't trust semicolon insertion.

Comment: @yc It's not a random bug and not understanding the issue should not be confused as a "bug source" and more than not understanding the "restricted production" rules. If you follow the *simple rules* in the *very few specific cases* (and write otherwise clean code) then there is no problem. More details can be follow here: [JavaScript Semicolon Insertion: Everything You Need To Know](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons). I've been bitten by this issue exactly *once*. After that it has never affected me again because of the consistent style and rules I use (sans semi-colons).

Comment: @yc In my experience it's much more easy to be bitten by not using braces uniformly used which is, sadly IMOHO, not stressed enough.

Answer (score -2):

it is hard to predict which one will execute first: `(function () {` or the `$(document).ready(function () {` try to combine those and declare all your functions before anything else

Comment: No it's not, the immediately executing function will execute first, always.

Comment: not in this case, Bomber.BoardFactory was undefined when the call to Bomber.Game() happened

Comment: That's because the call to Bomber.Game() wasn't happening in the $(document).ready handler, it was happening immediately because the OP left off a semicolon.

Comment: right, I remember now the confusion was between $(document).ready(function () { and function pageLoad() { not to be mistaken with self executing function, sry about that, my mistake