# Interesting and strange behaviour of objects and closure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, closures, prototype

See the code

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
function a()
{
    ;
}
a.prototype.hello = function()
{
    alert('hello');
}
(function()
    {
        var b = 8;
    }
());
</script>​
```

I'm not creating an object of a and not calling hello().But I'm getting the hello() called.

When I remove the closure ,the function is not automatically called.
ie. for

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
function a()
{
    ;
}
a.prototype.hello = function()
{
    alert('hello');
}
</script>
```

What is the reason for this strange behaviour?

http://jsfiddle.net/6yc9r/

and
http://jsfiddle.net/6yc9r/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does commenting out the alert() line of this code make it fail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824482/why-does-commenting-out-the-alert-line-of-this-code-make-it-fail)

Answer (score 4):

By omitting the semicolon, you are accidentally invoking the hello() function. This is why to use semicolons, even though the automatic semicolon insertion function of JS engines makes them **seem** like they're not necessary! Try this:

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
function a()
{
    ;
}
a.prototype.hello = function()
{
    alert('hello');
};
(function()
    {
        var b = 8;
    }
());
</script>​
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that you're missing a `;`.

Because there is no semicolon between the function expression and the `(` on the next line, the second function becomes a parameter to the first, like this:

```
a.prototype.hello = function()
{
    alert('hello');
}(function() { ... }());
```